# AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'raw_ratings'

Tags: python, pandas, recommendation-engine

I am getting an error while using the following command

```
trainset, testset = train_test_split(t2data, test_size=.15,train_size=0.85)
```

The dataset contains user rating, user ids and product ids.

error message:

```
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'raw_ratings'
```

My dataframe doesn't have any attribute by the name raw_ratings.

This is how I am reading the CSV:

```
rdata = pd.read_csv('ratings_Electronics.csv', header=0, names ['userid','productid','rating','timestamp'],skipinitialspace=True)
```

So i am unable to understand how this error is coming. Any help would be appreciated. thanks

detailed error:

---

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
 in ()
----> 1 trainset, testset = train_test_split(t2data, test_size=.15,train_size=0.85)

2 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in **getattr**(self, name)
5134             if self._info_axis._can_hold_identifiers_and_holds_name(name):
5135                 return self[name]
-> 5136             return object.**getattribute**(self, name)
5137
5138     def **setattr**(self, name: str, value) -> None:

AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'raw_ratings'

Comment: there may be some inappropriate data in your dataset, please have an insight of each column

Comment: Hello, have you found a solution for your problem?

Answer (score 3):

You may be using the wrong data type. Very much possible you are using panada data frame whereas surprise dataset is expected.

I found this example helpful https://github.com/NicolasHug/Surprise/issues/20
from NicholasHug.
Solution worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You are reading the CSV in `rdata` variable and splitting the `t2data`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply; i did some transformation in between (removing time stamp; considering only those user ids which have more than 50 ratings) and hence the new data set is t2data.

Comment: Thank you :) please upvote and if you want please accept my solution! Welcome to the opensource community

Comment: sorry; the issue isn't resolved. I replied to your comment on difference in dataset name.

Comment: Have you found any solution to the problem? I have the same issue